# Referring to parent attribute in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science-experience

This is my json

```
{
    "fInstructions": [
        {
            "id": 155,
            "type":"finstruction",
            "ref": "/spm/finstruction/155",
            "iLineItem":[
                {
                    "id": 156,
                    "type":"ilineitem",
                    "ref": "/spm/ilineitem/156",
                    "creationDate": "2018-03-09",
                    "dueDate":"2018-02-01",
                    "effectiveDate":"2018-03-09",
                    "frequency":"01",
                    "coveredPeriodFrom":"2018-02-28",
                    "coveredPeriodTo":"2018-02-28",
                    "statusCode":"PRO",
                    "amount": 6
                },
                {
                    "id": 157,
                    "type":"ilineitem",
                    "ref": "/spm/ilineitem/157",
                    "creationDate": "2018-03-09",
                    "dueDate":"2018-02-01",
                    "effectiveDate":"2018-03-09",
                    "frequency":"01",
                    "coveredPeriodFrom":"2018-03-01",
                    "coveredPeriodTo":"2018-03-31",
                    "statusCode":"PRO",
                    "amount": 192
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

If I do:

```
json_normalize(data['fInstructions'], record_path=['iLineItem'])
```

I get two rows as expected with all the ILIs.  However, I want to also have the parent attributes id, type in the result set.  To that I try:

```
json_normalize(df_data_1['fInstructions'], record_path=['iLineItem'], meta=['id', 'type'])
```

But then I get:
    ValueError: Conflicting metadata name id, need distinguishing prefix

So I try:

```
json_normalize(df_data_1['fInstructions'], record_path=['iLineItem'], meta=['fInstructions.id'])
```

Which gives me:

```
KeyError: "Try running with errors='ignore' as key 'fInstructions.id' is not always present"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
json_normalize(df_data_1['fInstructions'], record_path=['iLineItem'], meta='id', record_prefix='ils.')
```